# Search text from PDF files stored locally or in SQLite blob

Tags: react-native, sqlite

I need to store PDF documents in either a local storage or SQLite (React-native iOS/Android). The app needs to work offline, so documents should be indexed and searchable for offline viewing.

Any ideas of how I can implement it? if I store a document in SQLite as blob, is there any plugin I can use to search. OR if is there any search engine library for react-native that can index the document as soon as PDF is uploaded.

Thanks in advance for your help/suggestions.